# Access PHP protected properties

Tags: php

Hi there I have a class : AbstractEntityType with a protected property :

```
abstract class AbstractEntityType extends AbstractType {
  protected static $lists = null;

  public function __construct($lists = array()) {
    AbstractEntityType::$lists = $lists;
  }

  public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver) {
    $resolver->setRequired(array(
        'temp', 'statut'
    ));
  }
}
```

Here is another class extending the previous one :

```
class MyType extends AbstractEntityType {
   ....
}
```

I use a factory to create MyType class:

```
class SimpleFormTypeFactory {
  public function createType($entity_type, $entity_stub, $lists = null) {
      $type = null;

      switch($entity_type) {
           ....
           case SOMENUMTYP:
            $type = new MyType($lists);
            break;
      }
  }
```

I tested it locally with php 5.4 and windows with no problem but on the server (linux and php 5.3) I have this error :

```
Error: Cannot access protected property MyType::$lists
```

What is going on ? a php bug ?

Thank you

Answer (score 5):

The property is protected, so you can never do this:

```
public function __construct($lists = array()) {
    AbstractEntityType::$lists = $lists;
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ Not allowed for a protected property, regardless where you are
}
```

However, when you are inside your class, you can access it directly:

```
public function __construct($lists = array()) {
    self::$lists = $lists;
}
```

Comment: you are right about one thing : I should use self instead of the name of the class (though, like I said it works good on the test environment).

Comment: @mlwacosmos It shouldn't work in your test environment either. But I have never used php or a server on windows so I don't know what might cause that. Could be in the error handling but I would guess you would notice when it doesn't work correctly :-)

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake, the problem is not on the construction. Like I wrote it , it works. My problem is somewhere else. What you wrote before about "Not allowed for a protected property" does not seem right to me but I may be wrong. It is possible to call the static property in the abstract class. No constructor is defined in the children classes so they take the parent's one. (in Java it would be like that). I will ask another question concerning my problem.

Comment: @mlwacosmos No, it is right, you cannot use the class name to get a *protected* or *private* (static...) property. You can only get it from within the class itself using `self::` or from an extended class using `parent::`. The key here is **protected** or **private**, if it is a public property, you can do it the way you were doing it in the constructor. You are right about the children's classes using the parent's constructor but that is unrelated to the problem you are having.